# Layout problems within HorizontalScrollView

Tags: java, android

I have a custom control extending RadioGroup. I have a method to add custom radio button to RadioGroup (custom radio button has margins). So if i place my custom RadioGroup control inside HorizontalScrollView - it seems margins are lost. Then if soft keyboard shown - margins of radio button looks correct.

Screenshot of custom radiogroup control :
[image: Screenshot of custom radiogroup control]

Here is a some code of my RadioGroup control

```
public class EDRadioGroup extends RadioGroup implements RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener {

MarkerContainer mrk;
int markerContainerId;
DirectoryElement selectedElement;

public EDRadioGroup(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.init(null);
}

public EDRadioGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.init(attrs);
}

private void init(@Nullable AttributeSet attributeSet) {
    setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    if (attributeSet != null) {
        TypedArray a = this.getContext().getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attributeSet, R.styleable.ERadioGroup, 0, 0);
        try {
            if (a.hasValue(R.styleable.ERadioGroup_marker_container)) {
                markerContainerId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.ERadioGroup_marker_container, -1);
            }
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }
    }
}

public void fillRadioGroup(List<DirectoryElement> items) {
    if (items != null) {
        for (DirectoryElement item : items) {
            RadioButton rb = new YellowRadioButton(this.getContext());
            rb.setText(String.format("%s%s", item.getTitle().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase(), item.getTitle().substring(1)));
            rb.setTag(item);
            this.addView(rb);
        }
    }
}
```

}

This is custom RadioButton code:

```
public class YellowRadioButton extends AppCompatRadioButton {
public YellowRadioButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.init((AttributeSet)null);
}

public YellowRadioButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.init(attrs);
}

public YellowRadioButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    this.init(attrs);
}

private void init(@Nullable AttributeSet attributeSet) {
    this.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.radio_states_yellow));
    this.setButtonDrawable(null);
    this.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 16);
    this.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.dt_primary));
    int padding = (int) ScreenDimensionsHelper.convertDpToPixel(10, getContext());
    int minWidth = (int) ScreenDimensionsHelper.convertDpToPixel(80, getContext());
    setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
    setMinWidth(minWidth);
    setTextAlignment(TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    if (changed) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        int marging = (int) ScreenDimensionsHelper.convertDpToPixel(8, getContext());
        layoutParams.setMargins(marging, marging, marging, marging);
        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        this.invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: please add some code of xml

Comment: have you tried using marginStart on the radiobuttons?

Comment: i have added a code